# Runtime determine the type of nonterminal symbol of bison/yacc

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer, yacc

I want to parse a string like this "!x.z" and  "x.y  > 1",
Type of “x.z” is bool, type of "x.y" is int,but the type of "x.z" or "x.y" was determined on runtime;

x is OBJ_NAME,  z, and y is ATTR_NAME,  the type of ATTR_NAME was registered by other codes;

I can use function CreateExpr to create a Expr*, Expr is base class of IntExpr and BoolExpr， 
CreteExpr to crate IntExpr or BoolExpr based on the regstered informaiton;

```
Expr* CreateExpr(string obj, string attr)
{
     type = queryType(obj, attr);
     if(type == INT) return IntExpr(...);
     if(type == BOOL) return BoolExpr(...);
}
```

I want have grammar like this:

```
int_expr : obj_attr_expr  { $$ = dynamica_cast<IntExpr*>($1); }

bool_epxr : int_expr '>' int_expr    { $$ = new Greater($1, $3); }
          | '!' bool_expr            {  $$ = new NotExpr($2); }
          | obj_attr_expr            { $$ = dynamica_cast<BoolExpr*>($1); }
          | obj_attr_expr > int_expr { $$ =  new Greater(dynamica_cast<IntExpr*>($1), $3); }

obj_attr_expr : OBJ_NAME '.'  ATTR_NAME { $$ = CreateExpr($1, $3); }
```

Actually, it's wrong grammar since it can not decide obj_attr_expr is a int_expr or bool_expr.

Dose there have a solution ?

Now I parse  "OBJ_NAME '.'  ATTR_NAME" in Lexical analyzer and return a int_expr or bool_expr to grammar parser, but I want to move this function to grammar parser.

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to encode the types of expressions in the grammar like that. Just define one `expr` rule and let the type checker take care of distinguishing between the different types.

Comment: You don't need it at runtime. You already had it at compile time, and you threw it away.